# Could’nt install plugins in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation, plugins

I’m using wordpress.org- “oceanWp theme” and i’ve installed a plugin called “profile builder” then removed and tried to install it again, but I couldn’t.
As soon as I give install it loads and says “**Update Failed!**”.

ERROR MSG: “**Installation failed: Abort class-pclzip.php : Missing zlib extensions**”.

I also edited the file wp-admin/includes/class.pclzip.php and Changed all references of gzopen to gzopen64(had 3 references) but didn’t help.
I know I still can install plugins via Cpanel and filezila but I really want to solve this ERROR.

Thanks in advance:)
Host: Infinityfree.net
Wordpress version: Version 5.4.2
Profile builder plugin version: Version: 3.1.9
The page I need help with: https://makeitquick.ml